# Comparable Implementation not Working

Tags: java, comparable, implements

I have a class that implements comparable as shown in its signature:

```
public class PairNode<FirstType, SecondType> implements Comparable
```

This class compiles fine, and has a proper compareTo method.

In another class, it's constructor takes an ArrayList of comparable object in it's constructor, as shown here:

```
public HeapMinPriorityQueue(ArrayList<Comparable> list)
```

However, when later on, when I have an ArrayList of PairNodes, and I try to use the constructor like this:

```
HeapMinPriorityQueue pq = new HeapMinPriorityQueue(list);
```

Java tells me that they are incompatible types, as an ArrayList of PairNodes  of Characters and Integers can't be converted to an ArrayList of Comparables. But shouldn't they be equivalent, as my PairNode implements Comparable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Oh, thank you! I guess I presumed that they were polymorphic when they weren't!

Comment: Should be `implements Comparable<PairNode<FirstType,SecondType>>`

Comment: Note that `public HeapMinPriorityQueue(List<? extends Comparable<?>> list)` should work.

Comment: Even when I change it to Comparable<PairNode<FirstType,SecondType>>, it still gives me an error saying that it can't be converted.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you assylias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assylias answered this for me by posting a link, but Generic types aren't polymorphic, and therefore that was why it wasn't working. I am changing my class to specific version to remedy this. Thank you assylias!